# best way to write sql and if statement comparing two items inside a database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

attempting to code a new concept; however, not sure if its going to work well or not.  At this point I'm just playing around with an idea.

So, there is a table called defaultpermissions in my database and I have 2 columns, "name" and "status" where name is the permission and status states whether it is on or off ( 1 or 0 )

So then I have a list of checkboxes on a defaultpermissions page where the admin can set save the default permissions.

For each checkbox, it checks to find if that permission is on or off ( 1 or 0).

How is the best way to do this?

1. Will I have to run a new query for each permission  (get $status where $name = '$permission')
2. or can I do something to compare the two columns at once for each permission in a while statement?

Sorry its so general, but at this point its just a concept I'm trying to figure out and would love some help.

example:

some of the permissions

- Add Page     [checkbox]
- hide page    [checkbox]
- remove page  [checkbox]
- add content  [checkbox]
- edit content [checkbox]
- live editor  [checkbox]

database:

- name = addpage   status = 0
- name = hidepage  status = 1
- name = removepage status = 0
- name = addcontent  status = 1

etc. etc.

And for each one it needs to compare rows 'name' and 'status' to find out if its already active or not so it knows whether or not to check the box.  I don't mind doing a new query for each permission but theres a few so I figured that might be a bad thing.  Right now there are around 20 default permission options that can be checked on this page.
Thanks for your input ahead of time

P.S.  Semi new to PHP and learning as I go...if there is a  better way to set this up please let me know.

Comment: There are so many ways you could do this in <pick your language>/SQL.  I would look at a case statement for each checkbox in SQL and just set the value to what it is on the form.  I wouldn't worry about checking if it needs to be updated unless it's a requirement to store the previous value.  Otherwise, its a bunch of checking that doesn't need to be done.  If currentval is false and form is true then set true...not necessary.

Comment: It is very true that their are many ways to do this. By using the (if currentval <> initval) way, you can then make a page that has all your permissions and statuses on a single page and update them at once. Eventually that list will get long and doing the check will make it quite manageable. I work as a developer for [CoolStuffInc.com](http://coolstuffinc.com) and write html, php, and sql for 40+ hours and this is the system we use for product entry and managing employee logins etc.

Comment: The way I plan on setting this up if the list gets too long is to seperate the diff sections into diff pages (site management/content management/user management)...but I'm still confused on how I would set up the query, and each checkbox to make it all work...I don't know what (if currentval <> initial) is to be honest...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are well oriented. In order to improve the design probably is a good idea to identify..

- All permissions names/concepts
- All permissions status (identity if the values are common between permission names)

Now that you have all that info, analyze if a checkbox represents correctly what you want to represent. For instance a checkbox will be good to represent if permissions were granted or not, but it's not that good to represent states not associated with true/false.

If the latter is not your case, you will be able to create a list with labels and checkboxes representing the state of the default permission set. The query will be something like

Also consider to add another column to grant permission to users. You may use the username to filter each user's permission set and also the default set. For instance...

```
Select * from permissionsets where user like 'default' >> this will return the default set.
Select * from permissionsets where user like 'user1' >> this will return user1 permission set.
```

Do you think this will help?. Thanks!

@leo

Comment: This is what I am doing..I am allowing the admin to create defaults that will automatically get added to users who sign up at that time...they can go in a change defaults at any given time..there is another database that has all the user permissions for each user..that way the admin can go in and give each user diff permissions...but, can you help me with how to set up the checkboxes  allowing checked = true and unchecked = false...I need it to pull the setting that is saved inside database..for instance, if allow user to edit database is on, i need ti to call that into the table input

Comment: and I need to do this the best way possible so that I can do this for all 20 checkboxes.  I'm just not sure the best way to implement this being the true/false is on a sep column than the "name" of the permission...

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087038/checkbox-checked-or-unchecked-boolean-php-mysql) is an example you may use. Notice that is not complete but if you are familiar with php development would be easy to fill-in the missing parts. Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to your problem is the following:

- Add a hidden input field that holds the status of your permission (using your example this will be 1 or 0
- Using PHP, use a statement that is similar to the following:

`'<input type="checkbox" name="input Name Here" value="1"' . ($dbRow['Status'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' />';`

What the above does it it uses the status found from a db select and uses the status to default the box to checked.

- Next you can make a way (i use [switch statments](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp) in situations like this) to see if the values of the checkbox and hidden fields match.

> $checkBoxVal = ($_GET['checkBoxName'] ? 1 : ($_POST['checkBoxName'] ? 1 : 0));
>
> $hiddenVal = ($_GET['hiddenFieldName'] == 1 || $_POST['hiddenFieldName'] == 1 ? 1 : 0);
>
> if ($checkBoxVal <> $hiddenVal) {
>
> ```
> do updates here
> ```
>
> }//END IF

What this does is see if your checkbox is ticked. If it is then `$checkBoxVal` will be 1

It then compares it the the last value it was via the hidden input.

If they hidden field was 0 and you tick your box and submit your form, the values will not be the same and you can then do the updates you need.

For me this is a great way to change anything in a database if the initial values change (That is if you are not using jQuery `$.ajax` or XHR requests to do this dynamically.)

If you need more information about this or need an example let me know.

Hope this has helped. Good Luck. =)

Edit:

Your query should select your rows that you want to alter with the checkboxes.

> SELECT name, status FROM defaultpermissions

Then you would use PHPs' `mysql_fetch_assoc` function on the result query kinda like this

> while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>
> //Do your input fields in here using $row as your returned row
>
> }//END WHILE LOOP

Maybe this will make it a bit clearer =)

Comment: This makes sense, but what about the query for the database for this?  I have the name of the permission under one column and the true/false saved under another...how would it compare the two using your code?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect how you can achieve using your database data in a loop. Maybe you can use a table and for every loop add a `<tr>` with each row of data from your database. =)